# Kurento node Hello World tutorial not connecting to Kurento Server on AWS

Tags: kurento

When running the kurento_hello_world Nodejs tutorial the Kurento Client fails to connect with my Kurento Media Server running on AWS.  **However, the corresponding Browser Javascript tutorial works fine with the exact same setup**.

My setup includes a Kurento Media Server running on an EC2 instance.  This was installed using the publicly available CloudFormation config for the server.  I have configured the certificates correctly and ensured my browsers trust them.

I have the tutorials installed and running from a separate EC2 instance.  I am using version 6.10.0 of the tutorials (however, I experience the same with 6.9.0).

I am testing this using Chrome.

For the Browser JavaScript Hello World tutorial I updated the js/index.js file to include:

```
var args = getopts(location.search,
{
  default:
  {
    // ws_uri: 'wss://' + location.hostname + ':8433/kurento',
    ws_uri: 'wss://<IP_Of_KMS_On_AWS>:8433/kurento', // Kurento server on AWS
    ice_servers: undefined
  }
});
```

This results in the tutorial working fine.  I see both video stream in the browser and logs in the KMS log file.

For the Node Hello World tutorial I updated the server.js file to include:

```
var argv = minimist(process.argv.slice(2), {
    default: {
      // as_uri: 'https://localhost:8443/',
      as_uri: 'https://<IP_Of_Application_Server>:8443/', // Application server on EC2
      // ws_uri: 'ws://localhost:8888/kurento'
        ws_uri: 'wss://<IP_Of_KMS_On_AWS>:8433/kurento', // Kurento server on AWS
    }
});
```

In the Node tutorial, the basic browser elements work fine, however the application fails to make successful connections to the KMS.  I don't see anything in the KMS logs.  I see the local video displayed in the browser, with a spinner in the remote video element.  This is a similar experience I've had with other Node Kurento tutorials, i.e. no calls being made to the KMS instance on AWS.

I am expecting that based on my configuration the Hello World Node tutorial should work the same as the Browser Javascript tutorial and I should see both video streams in the browser and logs being generated on the Kurento server.

Open questions:
1) Does my configuration look correct?
2) Am I missing something in my setup?

Comment: Hi,
Can you please check whether you have configured KMS default port 8888 to 8443 correctly.

Comment: @BuddhikaJayawardhana - I believe they are setup correctly.  If you notice, my setup works fine when I run the browser Javascript version of the tutorial.  Are you saying that the node.js version of the tutorial uses different ports on the KMS?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem today. After setting up the ec2 instance with Kurento i followed the steps laid out in [hello-world nodejs tutorial](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/6.13.0/tutorials/node/tutorial-helloworld.html), (changed last step, [see why](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-node#parameters) ):

```
git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-node.git
cd kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-hello-world
git checkout 6.13.0
npm install
cd static
bower install --allow-root
cd ..
npm start -- --as_uri=https://0.0.0.0:8081/ npm start -- --ws_uri=ws://0.0.0.0:8888/kurento
```

I saw the same behaviour in the browser: I could see local stream video being displayed, but not the remote stream, but unlike you I saw this log in my ec2 terminal:

```
/home/ubuntu/kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-hello-world/node_modules/express-session/index.js:142
    if (req.session) return next();
            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'session' of undefined
    at session (/home/ubuntu/kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-hello-world/node_modules/express-session/index.js:142:13)
    at WebSocketServer.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-hello-world/server.js:90:5)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at WebSocketServer.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at handleUpgrade (/home/ubuntu/kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-hello-world/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket-server.js:90:18)
    at WebSocketServer.completeUpgrade (/home/ubuntu/kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-hello-world/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket-server.js:329:5)
    at WebSocketServer.handleUpgrade (/home/ubuntu/kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-hello-world/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket-server.js:245:10)
    at Server.upgrade (/home/ubuntu/kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-hello-world/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket-server.js:89:16)
    at emitThree (events.js:136:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:217:7)
```

I found [this thread](https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/605) that helped me with solving this problem. From the thread:

> the problem was that the source was using an old version of ws which
>   since the writing of the code has removed ws.upgradeReq

I checked the [GitHub page](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-node/blob/master/kurento-hello-world/server.js) for the code of server.js and saw that the `if (req.session) return next();` part got changed. I removed the /kurento-tutorial-node project from my ec2 and took all the steps from the  hello-world nodejs tutorial BUT WITHOUT `git checkout 6.13.0` in order to get the new version of the code. So I did:

```
git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-node.git
cd kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-hello-world
npm install
cd static
bower install --allow-root
cd ..
npm start -- --as_uri=https://0.0.0.0:8081/ npm start -- --ws_uri=ws://0.0.0.0:8888/kurento
```

and this time it worked

[image]